# change user for Exec Runner in Drone

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-18.04, drone.io

I've set up the `Drone` on my remote `Ubuntu 18.04` `Linux` host. To make it easy I've installed `drone-runner-exec`. I've successfully connected it to my `GitHub` etc. So now it works fine, i.e. it clones the repository and begins to run my pipeline.
One of steps is simple bash script that have to update subfolders in the repo.

```yaml
steps:
- name: Getting subfolders
  commands:
  - ./my_script
```

The runner executes the script but fails on some points. After searching I've found the scripts executed under user I've installed the `Drone`. I see in `ps aux` output that both `docker` and `drone` run under `root`.

So my question - how can I change the system user under which the runner runs?

Answer (score 5):

A bit late for the OP, but I've just solved the same problem on my system (Ubuntu), so sharing it to help others navigated here.

Let's say `someuser` is the user you want to run the `drone-runner-exec` service with.

Follow the [official docs](https://docs.drone.io/runner/exec/installation/linux/) to download and configure the exec runner, but create the config file in the home dir of your desired user. After that:

**Install the service first, using the config file in your user home:**

```sh
sudo drone-runner-exec service install --config="/home/someuser/.drone-runner-exec/config"
```

**Override the service to use another user:**

```sh
sudo systemctl edit drone-runner-exec
```

**Save the override file with:**

```
[Service]
User=someuser
Group=somegroup
```

**Start the service:**

```sh
sudo drone-runner-exec service start
```

**Check:**

```sh
ps -ef |grep drone-runner-exec
```

You should see `someuser` for the UID (instead of `root`)